Base network : Using smart wallet doesn't trigger events on target contracts
I am trying to integrate the Coinbase smart wallet (not to be confused with Coinbase wallet) in my daap that also utilizes an event indexer (subquery).
My problem is that the smart wallet, being a smart contract not an actual wallet, doesn't seem to call my contracts like a regular wallet would do resulting in chain updates but no events being triggered to be caught then by my indexer.
Is this a known issue with the Base network, what might be a solution to mitigate this ?
Note : everything works fine with standard private key wallets

Without knowing the details and having example source code, it is not possible to know what you are doing, but you are likely doing it wrong. There should very little differences between smart contract based accounts and EOAs from the smart contract development point of view.
